# how to increment an id in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
// mongoose Schema is what is used to define attributes for our documents
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//connect to a MongoDB database
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/student');
//Connection establishment between mongoose and mongodb
mongoose.connect('connected', function() {
    console.log("database connected successfully")
});


var userSchema = new Schema({

    id:{
        type:Number,
            unique:true,
            autoIndexId:true
    },
    Name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
                unique:false
    },
    Age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
},   {
    collection: ('studentcollection')
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

function createStudent(name, age, cb) {
    var list = new User({
            id:4,
        Name: name,
        Age: age
    });

    list.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb();
    });
}

function listStudent(cb) {
    User.find({}, function(err, studentcollection) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb(null, studentcollection);
    }).select('-__v');
}


exports.createStudent = createStudent;
exports.listStudent = listStudent;

User.findByIdAndRemove(2,function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("deleted");
});
```

this is my  code, i need to increment the id when ever i receive the data from server it should be unique and also when i delete an  id, the id value must also update. I came across the auto-incremental but when i delete an particular Id it does not update the id. Is their any other method so i can increment id .

Comment: `findByIdAndRemove` requires an `_id` field yet here you are referring to the custom `id` field, which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0):

use [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) module,

```
var mongoose = require('../lib/mongoose');
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
    companySchema = require('./company').Company;

autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose);

var schema = new Schema({
    itemId: {
        type: Number,
    },
    itemName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    providerCompany: [{
        type: String,
    }]

});

var productSchema = mongoose.model('Product', schema);

schema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {model: 'Product', field: 'itemId'});
module.exports.Product = productSchema;
```

https://github.com/miroslav-grabinskiy/Api/blob/master/Avalon/models/product.js